# Notification for failure steps in AWS Codepipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline

How to trigger notification for step /action failure in AWS Codepipeline?

Answer (score 7):

AWS CodePipeline now provides notifications on pipeline, stage, and action status changes.
https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/09/aws-codepipeline-now-provides-notifications-on-pipeline-stage-and-action-status-changes/

Answer (score 1):

AWS now added support for notification using cloudwatch and SNS.  See:

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/09/aws-codepipeline-now-provides-notifications-on-pipeline-stage-and-action-status-changes/